# How to make a Dungeons and Dragons-esque skill check in Python?

Tags: python, dice

I am trying to make a small text-based adventure game in Python IDLE, but I am running into some issues with having the game give a different response if the player rolls above or below the DC of a DND style preception check. I am very new to this so it's probably an easy fix. Here's the code.

[I have no idea how to input the code into the question correctly so here is a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fzrX.png)
BTW I did import random at the beginning of the code its just too far back to include in the screencap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example otherwise you might be at risk of users downvoting you.  the {} in the editor allows you to paste code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are not specifying what numbers the random module to choose from, in the line `if random.randint > 10:`. To fix this, put the numbers you want it to choose between. For example, if you want it to choose a random number between 1 and 20, your line would become `if random.randint(1,20) > 10:`.
You will also want to do this for the other line, which reads `if random.randint < 10:`.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO,

Please read the minimal reproducible example guide posted in the comments by D.L. First thing I would do is to post the actual code, because if the link expires, then others viewing this post with a similar issue cannot figure out what was the given example, and how it was solved.

With logistics out of the way, to fix the error you are specifically receiving is to put what is rolled in a variable.

Here are a few things I would change to make your code clear

```
# Some string that receives yes or no
room_2_input = ("...")

# if condition is yes
if room_2_input == 'yes':
    # Put it in a variable
    roll = random.randint(1,20)
    # You do not have to format a string this way, but I think it makes it easier
    print('You rolled {}'.format(roll)

    # Put this condition within the first if, because you don't 
    # need to execute it if they do not choose to roll
    # Neither of your original condition has inclusivity, so if 10 is rolled,
    # your program will do nothing, because neither condition would be met
    if roll >= 10:
        '''do stuff'''
    # I would only include elif < 10 if you are specifically looking for > 2
    # outcomes, but your outcome appears to be binary, either above or below 10
    else:
        '''do stuff'''
```

The reason you would not do a `random.randint(1,20) > 10:`  check in your second if statement is because you would be executing a different roll than your first one.